# setting default value in dynamic select element

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form>
    <select ng-model="aSelect"
      ng-options="i for i in range">
    </select>  
  </form>
</body>
```

The range is specified in the controller as [1,2,3]. How do I set one of these values as the selected value? Plunker can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2HjvYVEqkslGNSsErXr2?p=preview

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ngInit`:

```
<select ng-init="aSelect = 1" ng-model="aSelect" ng-options="i for i in range">
</select>
```

Comment: how does this work when the first item in the range is not 1?